# React TSParticles route change renders in root

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Having a problem with TSParticles, when I change my routes very quickly the TSParticle component renders late and causes it to render as a child of the root, instead of a child of my component that I am positioning the particles in, this causes some very bad visual bug where it will cause layout shift in my page. I am using the `{ fullScreen: enabled }` option to be able to absolute my particles div inside specific components.

I have tried creating a sort of destroy method so that if the route changes then it will not render the component but it doesn't seem to be working.

I am also using lazy loading for my route components.

Here is my TSParticle component currently:

```
import { useCallback, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Particles from "react-tsparticles";
import type { Engine } from "tsparticles-engine";
import { loadSlim } from "tsparticles-slim";

const _Particles = ({ id }: any) => {
  const [destroy, setDestroy] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [startPath, setStartPath] = useState<string>("");
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  const particlesInit = useCallback(async (engine: Engine) => {
    setLoaded(false);
    await loadSlim(engine);
  }, []);

  const particlesLoaded = useCallback(async () => {
    setLoaded(true);
  }, [startPath]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setStartPath(pathname);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (pathname !== startPath) {
      setDestroy(true);
    };
  }, [pathname]);

  if (destroy) return <></>;
  return (
    <Particles
      id={"tsparticles-" + id}
      url="/particlesjs-config.json"
      init={particlesInit}
      loaded={particlesLoaded}
      className="pointer-events-none h-screen"
      style={{
        opacity: loaded ? 1 : 0,
        filter: "drop-shadow(0 0 6px #EA6500)",
        transition: "opacity 2s",
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default _Particles;
```